# Localization is not working in Jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have calendar functionality in my application.I am referring from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. I had seen the "Localize Calendar" example in that web page.But there itself localization is not working.Is it bug or anything i need to do extra.

My Code

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );

        $("#w_datePicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "style/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            altField: '#show_date_on_select',
            altFormat: 'DD, MM d',
            //dateFormat: 'DD, MM d',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                //var selDate = FormatDate(dateText);
                //$("#show_date_on_select").html(selDate);
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess you need to have a language file for your selected language as well. From here: [Datepicker Language File](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n)

Comment: @Roemer language file url updated, thanks for commenting

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {clearText: 'Effacer', clearStatus: '',
    closeText: 'Fermer', closeStatus: 'Fermer sans modifier',
    prevText: '&lt;Préc', prevStatus: 'Voir le mois précédent',
    nextText: 'Suiv&gt;', nextStatus: 'Voir le mois suivant',
    currentText: 'Courant', currentStatus: 'Voir le mois courant',
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
    'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
    monthStatus: 'Voir un autre mois', yearStatus: 'Voir un autre année',
    weekHeader: 'Sm', weekStatus: '',
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
    dayStatus: 'Utiliser DD comme premier jour de la semaine', dateStatus: 'Choisir le DD, MM d',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0, 
    initStatus: 'Choisir la date', isRTL: false};
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

The link for most of the languages: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.20/ui/i18n/
as [Sudhir said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578270/662581)

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. but other languages link is not working
Look that https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Answer (score 1):

1. First check there is all required language files are there or not. If you want to download language files for datepicker then you can download from below link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n
2. If you put file path into header section and it is not working then please move the script tag from header to body.

Above steps are working for me.